# Design Pattern for logging in Multi threaded system

Tags: python, multithreading, design-patterns

How can we make use of design pattern for log generation in Multi threaded environment. There is one log file and there are multiple threads need to write in this log file. So there has to be a mechanism that each thread can access the same file handler once it is created.
Should i use Singleton or Factory design pattern as there is only point of installation of object or there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do you care about collating or ensuring accurate time sequencing of log messages in any way?  If not, @dano is right and you should be good to go just using `logging`.

Comment: @SilasRay do you have a suggestion for those interested in collating and sequence accuracy?

Comment: It becomes much more complicated.  I don't know anything off hand, and a quick Google search didn't turn up anything, but I could think of some things (though not small) to start to tackle the problem.  If you want to collate things from a thread, you'll probably need a buffer of some sort.  If you want to collate across threads, or maintain temporal order, you'll probably need a queue with a manager in a master thread, keeping track of what threads are alive, then sorting messages as they come in from the workers before dumping them to the file.  Then there's metadata (datetime, etc)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is actually [thread-safe by default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#thread-safety):

> The logging module is intended to be thread-safe without any special
>   work needing to be done by its clients. It achieves this though using
>   threading locks; there is one lock to serialize access to the module’s
>   shared data, and each handler also creates a lock to serialize access
>   to its underlying I/O.